# FFMPEG WATERMARK EVERY 2 mins from left to right or vice versa

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay, watermark

I'm just a new ffmpeg user and I just want to know how to watermark my 5 mins video with watermark appearing every 2 minutes of the video and appearing from LEFT to RIGHT or vice versa?

please? anyone?

Thanks and Regards,

Stephen

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? What research have you done? :)

Comment: you could use Aegisub for this task

Comment: this is the only thing i've tried but i dont know how to make it appear every 2 mins :)

`ffmpeg -i birds.mp4 -i watermark.png \
-filter_complex "overlay='if(gte(t,1), -w+(t-1)*200, NAN)':(main_h-overlay_h)/2" birds4.mp4`

Comment: Aegisub is for subtitle? they do have watermark also?

Comment: aegisub is like photoshop for subtitles - you can do there anything you want, even watermarks

Comment: Cool, Trying now :)

Answer (score 0):

save this script as birds.ass

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.2.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+
WrapStyle: 0
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes
YCbCr Matrix: TV.601
PlayResX: 1920
PlayResY: 1080

[Aegisub Project Garbage]
Audio File: E:/birds.mp4
Video File: E:/birds.mp4
Video AR Mode: 4
Video AR Value: 1.777778
Video Zoom Percent: 0.500000
Video Position: 2999

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Calibri,60,&H849F9F9F,&H000000FF,&HFF000000,&H00000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,0,9,60,60,60,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:02:00.00,Default,,0,0,0,,{\move(1860,60,332,60,0,119968)}WATERMARK
```

this is a simple .ass script where logo/watermark moves across the screen from right to left with constant speed for durration of 2 minutes (in this case I used 25fps video). 
 ofc it can be costumized anyhow you wish... font, color, opacity, movment, shape, effects...

**example 2:** `{\move(1860,60,318,60,0,29970)}WATERMARK`
logo will apear at video duration 00:02:00.000 on the top right corner and it will travel to top left corner in 30 seconds

and then just hardsub it with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i birds.mp4 -vf birds.ass -c:v libx264 -preset slower -b:v 0 -crf 21 -c:a copy final.mp4
```

let me know if you need further guidance...

Comment: oh wow thank you so much! I just got home and will try this :)